# Get vector angle by python

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a vector list. I want to get angle in each vector.

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([[-3, 4],
              [-2, -5],
              [2, 6],
              [3, -10]])

inv = np.arctan(v[:, 1] / v[:, 0])
degree = np.degrees(inv)
print(degree)  # get [-53.13010235,  68.19859051,  71.56505118, -73.30075577]

# use arctan2
inv = np.arctan2(v[:, 1] / v[:, 0])
degree = np.degrees(inv)
print(degree)  # get [ 126.86989765, -111.80140949,   71.56505118,  -73.30075577]
```

but I want to get [127, 248 , 71, 286] (0~360 angle).
How to solve?

Comment: Your displayed output and required output don't seem to match up. After all, for the third element in the list, you are already getting 71.57...

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to use `arctan2()`?

Comment: Are you looking for [`arctan2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use modulus to get all the angles in the range 0 - 360.

```
import numpy as np

v = [
    [-3, 4],
    [-2, -5],
    [2, 6],
    [3, -10],
]

v = np.array(v)
inv = np.degrees(np.arctan2(*v.T[::-1])) % 360.0
print(inv)
```

**output**

```
[ 126.86989765  248.19859051   71.56505118  286.69924423]
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you ought to use `np.arctan2` rather than `np.arctan`
since the former takes care of choosing the correct quadrant.
By default both `np.arctan2` and `np.arctan` return values 
in `[-pi, pi]` range, so in order to get `[0, 360]` range in degrees you
can use `degrees = np.mod(np.degrees(inv), 360)`.

```
import numpy as np

v = np.array([[-3, 4],
              [-2, -5],
              [2, 6],
              [3, -10]])

inv = np.arctan2(v[:, 1], v[:, 0])
degree = np.mod(np.degrees(inv), 360)
print(degree)  # get [-53.13010235,  68.19859051,  71.56505118, -73.30075577]
```